# How to save tuplas values, to later search on it

Tags: java, sorting, arraylist

**Scenario**

I have some values of the type : (Name - Email)

From this couples of data, I have to set a ArrayList of "Name" values,something  like:  `|Name1|Name2| --- |NameN|` to set a Spinner. (Ordered alphabetically)

When I choose some Name in the spinner, I have to save the Email associated, to send it to other site.

**Problem**

My problem, is that I don't know, how to do this.

I mean, how I have to save all this tuplas, for once I selected the name, search it in the data? What kind of array/hashmap/hastable.... I have to use to save it?

May be a image would help a bit.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like a standard problem which would be well served by some sort of `Map`.  The keys would be the names, and the values would be the emails associated with those names.

```
public class Spinner {
    private Map<String, String> nameMap = new HashMap<String, String>();

    // associate an email with a given name
    public void setEmail(String name, String email) {
        nameMap.put(name, email);
    }

    // obtain an email associate with a given name
    public void getEmail(String name) {
        return nameMap.get(name);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if user can have more than one email save it  in a multivalueMap

https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/apidocs/org/apache/commons/collections4/MultiMap.html

Guava has another version too

http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Multimap.html

this kind of map one key can can have more than one value.

using  @Tim answer